# How to update Wordpress and plugins at specific day and time in PHP?

Tags: functions, updates, automatic-updates

We use automatic updates on our sites due to having many sites and so manual updates not being feasible in the low hosting costs.

But due to Wordpress or mainly plugin updates having the possibility to break your site, and due to not knowing when Wordpress would actually do the updates which could also occur every day, I would like to programatically update Wordpress and plugins in a functions.php or plugin so I can know the exact date and time it will run, and so we know to check for problems afterwards.

For example, I may choose Monday mornings 3am so our first action that morning is check all sites are working well, fix any issues, and then I know the rest of the week will be problem free :)

**Does anyone know how to initiate a Wordpress and plugin update in the functions file or a plugin?**

My idea is to disable all automatic updates generally, but then at a certain day and time to call the update function which would check if updates exist, and if they do, update them. I will add an email function to inform me what has been updated on what site so I can check that site.

If using automatic updates, this approach is far more controlled than if leaving Wordpress do it as and when it likes however many times every day.

Thanks

Comment: You can do a scheduled task everyday and put in the wp update function if the wp version has changed or if it is a new w version.

Answer (score 1):

There's a question and an answer regarding WP (auto) updates here, [How To/What triggers a Wordpress auto update?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183202/how-to-what-triggers-a-wordpress-auto-update)

The answer also has a link to a blog post on how to [force WordPress auto-update](http://blog.birdhouse.org/2013/11/02/force-wordpress-auto-update/).

Code snippet posted on the referenced blog,

```
<?php
  // request-update.php
  require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
  wp_maybe_auto_update();
?>
```

and

```
php ./request-update.php
```

Perhaps you can use this and a real (not WP) cron job to update your site(s) at a certain day and time.

**Edit**

Then there's the [`do_core_upgrade`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_core_upgrade/) function.

**Edit 2**

Oh, and then there's [`wp_update_plugins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_plugins/) and [`wp_update_themes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_themes/), too. These are defined in [wp-includes/update.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1/src/wp-includes/update.php) (trac).

**Edit 3**

Actually, [`wp_ajax_update_plugin`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_update_plugin/) might be better reference point for creating a custom plugin update process. There's also the [`Plugin_Upgrader`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/plugin_upgrader/) class. For themes there's [`wp_ajax_update_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_update_theme/) for reference and [`Theme_Upgrader`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/theme_upgrader/) class.

Comment: So the WP update functions will check if an update exists in WP AND plugins, and only update if it does? So we dont need to worry about checking if updates exist, just run the update at a scheduled time and all is taken care of?

Comment: It looks like the `run`method from `WP_Automatic_Updater` which the `wp_maybe_auto_update` uses does exaclty that. It checks if there are any updates for plugins, themes and core. If there is, it processes them.

Answer (score 0):

wp-disable-plugin-update.php smart updating knowledge growth WordPress code

```
/**
 * Prevent update notification for plugin
 * http://www.thecreativedev.com/disable-updates-for-specific-plugin-in-wordpress/
 * Place in theme functions.php or at bottom of wp-config.php
 */
function disable_plugin_updates( $value ) {
  if ( isset($value) && is_object($value) ) {
    if ( isset( $value->response['plugin-folder/plugin.php'] ) ) {
      unset( $value->response['plugin-folder/plugin.php'] );
    }
  }
  return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```