# How to schedule Automatic Wordpress Plugin and Core updates for night times

Tags: automatic-updates

I don't want to update plugins within business hours. Is there a way to schedule for after 1 am? Maybe via a hook or a setting in wp-config.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a cronjob that runs on 1am every 24 hours. With WP CLI this would be something like:

```
wp core update && wp plugin update --all && wp theme update
```

So you just create a .sh script, put the above in it, and run the script with a cronjob.

Comment: Ok, good idea. So I would deactivate automatic updates in WordPress itself and do it with wp cli, right?

Comment: I tried this. My problem is that I can only add conjobs for urls and not for shell scripts. So I tried to do this via exec_shell but that is prevented either. WP CLI is good but maby not for everyone. Another idea how to schedule the build in updates somehow?

Comment: Hi Marc, take a look at this solution, as it seems to be right what you are looking for:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329683/how-to-update-wordpress-and-plugins-at-specific-day-and-time-in-php

Comment: I accept this as the best answer.  In the end used another server to ssh into the wp server and execute this command: wp core update && wp plugin update --all && wp theme update but I had to add the --path=/www/htdocs/myfolder to it. Thank you!