# What triggers WordPress automatic updates? (revisited)

Tags: admin, updates, core, automatic-updates

I'm trying to ascertain what triggers WordPress automatic updates. (focusing core-updates for now, not plugin/theme at this time.)

[How To/What triggers a Wordpress auto update?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183202/how-to-what-triggers-a-wordpress-auto-update)

The 8 year old question above has an answer that explains how `_maybe_update_core` function (via `admin_init`) works.  After checking the latest source code, the answer still seems to be valid.  In that case, however, automatic updates would not be performed unless an admin page is opened.  Is that correct?  What happens if no one signs in to the admin page?